# How to disable the .net panel using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to disable the .net panel using JavaScript at page load

Here is my code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_schoolname" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" BorderColor="Firebrick" BorderStyle="Double">
//Design
</asp:Panel>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var panel = document.getElementById('<%=pnl_schoolname.ClientID%>');
            alert(panel.enable);
            panel.enable = false;

        };
    </script>
```

In alert it is showing the undefined.

Comment: "Enable**d**" is a server-side property used by ASP.NET, you can't access it from the client. asp:Panel just renders as a `<div>` so you can just use normal CSS `display` style to show/hide it, or you may be able to add a `disabled` attribute to the div instead to make it un-usable.

Answer (score -2):

I think it doesn't work because ClientIDMode is Static.

Try

```
document.getElementById('pnl_schoolname')
```

Why not disabling using VB-Code?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load
    pnl_schoolname.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If ClientIDMode is static then the value generated by `<%=pnl_schoolname.ClientID%>` would just be "pnl_schoolname" anyway so this would make no difference. The real problem is that enabled (or enable as the OP had it) is not a property of the `<div>` that is rendered as the output of the asp:Panel control.